# How to ensure all pipe buffer has been read?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

I have an app on Windows which has two threads:

`First one` - is reading information from some external storage and writing it to a pipe via `WriteFile`

`Second one` - is reading information from the pipe using `ReadFile`and doing some manipulation with it.

I am using usual anonymous pipe created via `CreatePipe`. So my question is - when I close the pipe in the writing thread sometimes the reading thread has not finished reading, which leads to a broken pipe. So how can I ensure, that all written information has been read before closing the pipe?

Comment: Depending on context, it might be more sensible to wait until both threads have exited before closing the handles.

Answer (score 1):

You could try `FlushFileBuffers()` before closing the pipe.

Another option would be to create two event objects with `CreateEvent()`.  When the writing thread is done writing, signal the first event with `SetEvent()` and wait for the second event to be signaled using `WaitForSingleObject()` before then closing the pipe (or writing the next data block).  When the reading thread detects the first event has been signaled, read from the pipe until there is nothing left to read and then signal the second event using `SetEvent()`.

Comment: I am already using this solution, but I thought that there are some inner mechanism to check pipe I/O operation status